# Understanding Python style, default parameters of functions

Tags: python, function, default-parameters

This is covered by the Python Tutorial, but I still don't quite understand the reason why Python has this style. Is it purely convention, or is there some explanation behind why Python has the following style regarding default parameters:

My understanding is that Python prefers `something=None` as opposed to `something=[]` for default parameters for functions. But...why not use `something=[]`? Surely this is the convention in other languages, like C

As an example, take these two examples, which are equivalent

```
def function(arr, L=[]):
    L.append(arr)
    return L
```

and

```
def function(arr, L=None):
    if L is None:
        L = []
    L.append(arr)
    return L
```

My understanding is that the first is "incorrect style" for Python. Why?

EDIT: Ah, I finally understand. I am incorrect above: the two functions are NOT equivalent. Default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time the function is called!

Comment: See http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

Comment: They *could* have had a block of code (like a lambda) run every time the function is called and create a *new* empty list. However this would 1. reduce performance unnecessarily, and 2. Make memoization/cache style code harder to write. Honestly it's a blessing that Python handles default arguments the way it does.

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Re your EDIT; Yes perfect :) Glad we could help!

Answer (score 5):

When you set a parameter to the value of a list, it is assigned when the function is defined, not when it is called.  That is why you'll get different results for calling the function multiple times with the same input parameter.  Beware!!!

```
def function(arr, L=[]):
    L.append(arr)
    return L

arr = [1, 2, 3]

>>> function(arr)
[[1, 2, 3]]

>>> function(arr)
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

A default value that's an empty list will refer to one specific variable each time you call it, instead of creating a new empty list every time.

```
>>> def add(defList=[]):
        defList.append(1)
        return defList
>>> add()
[1]
>>> add()
[1,1]
```

It's a quirk of how mutable data works in Python. It could be occasionally useful, but often it's safer to use `None`. Then create an empty list if a value hasn't been passed.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that Python stores a value for `L`. In other words `L` is a **reference** to a constant. But that **constant can be updated**.

You can say that Python stores it as:

```
               |-->  []
               |
function (arr, L)
```

But that `[]` is an ordinary object (thus with state), that can be modified as well. Now if the **function can modify or return `L`**, you start modifying the state of `L`. In the example:

```
def function(arr, L=[]):
    L.append(arr)
    return L
```

You **modify `L`**. If you call this the first time (for instance with `function(123)`), the object is updated so, now it is represented as:

```
               |-->  [123]
               |
function (arr, L)
```

As a result the behavior of `function` depends on a global state. In general a global state is seen as a bad smell in code design and furthermore it is not what people might expect. This doesn't hold for `None`, since you modify the local reference `L` (not the object itself).

You can say that the object is the same, but each time you call the function, you **copy a reference** to a local variable `L`.

Now for the second case:

```
                  |--> None
                  |
def function(arr, L):
    if L is None:
        L = []
    L.append(arr)
    return L
```

If you call this method, you assign a value to `L`, but `L` itself is not global (only the object to which `L` refers). So if you call this method, after the `if`, the function (in progress) will look like.

Answer (score 1):

Because the argument `l` is assigned an initial value of `[]` **NOT** when you call the function but when it's first declared and the module it's in is interpreted.

See: [Python: Common Gotcha](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) (*Thanks @ferhat elmas*)

**Example:** (*showing what's going on*)

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar 19 2015, 22:32:11) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def f(L=[]):
...     L.append(1)
...     return id(L), L
... 
>>> def g(L=None):
...     L = [] if L is None else L
...     L.append(1)
...     return id(L), L
...
```

We'll ignore what happens when you pass in another list to the `L` argument because that behaviour is well defined and acceptable. (*takes a list, appends to it and returns it*).

```
>>> f()
(139978918901088, [1])
>>> g()
(139978918964112, [1])
```

The first time we call `f()` and `g()` we might mistakenly think that we have successfully returned a new list from an initial empty one right? What what happens when we call `f()` again compared with the correct `g()`:

```
>>> f()
(139978918901088, [1, 1])
>>> g()
(139978918964112, [1])
```

So the initial value you assigned for the argument `L` is set once and only only when the function is defined; not when it's called. This is a common gotcha as explained in the link aove.

**NB:** `id()` here returns the unique identity of objects so you can clearly see why the first is an incorrect way to define a default value for a mutable object such as a list.

**Also Note:** In the above examples that the identity of `L` does not change when calling `f()`.